# Add elements to the DOM then remove them after n seconds?

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6, reactjs

I want to create animation effect on click. I need to append element and remove it in 3 sec on every click. Not one element, if users clicks 100 times in 3 seconds, I should append 100 elements and remove it.

```
click() {
  // create element
  // append element to div
  // remove in 3 sec
}
render() {
   return (
     <div className="main" onClick={this.click}>Click it</div>
   )
}
```

It's easy to do with vanila JS / JQuery

```
click() {
  let elm = $('</div>');
  elm.addClass('animation');
  $('.main').append(elm);
  setTimeout(() => {
     elm.remove();
  }, 3000);
}
```

**Should I use React to render these elements(`.map, setState`,...) or I can use vanilla JS(`appendChild`, `removeChild`)?**

Simple example in JQuery - https://jsfiddle.net/W4Km8/10107/

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
this.state = { items: [] }

addItem() {
  const newItem = (<span>hello</span>)

  this.setState({ items: this.state.items.concat(newItem) }, () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({ items: this.state.items.filter(i => i !== newItem) })
    }, 3000)
  })
}

render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="main" onClick={this.addItem}>Click it</div>
      {this.state.items.map((item, i) =>
        <div key={i}>{item}</div>
      )}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Do you think this solution is better than vanilla JS? What would you use in this case?

Comment: @Dilan In React you shouldn't be directly manipulating the DOM unless you absolutely need to. So yes, this yes is "better" than vanilla JS when working with React

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot. I wanted double check it. Vanilla JS is more easy way in this case and I don't need to re-render component on every click. It's why I asked it.

Comment: @Dilan Honestly, I don't know if you can manipulate React's virtual DOM with the vanilla JS methods to manipulate the "real" DOM. I hope the author of the other answer has tested his code. I tested mine by the way and it works. :)

Comment: I tested vanilla JS, it works too without any errors and warnings. But everybody says - "Don't manipulate DOM in React". :)

Comment: Great answer ! You could simplify the filter with: `items.filter(i => i !== newItem)`

Comment: @naomik Indeed! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Without jQuery, just use the built-in vanilla JS functions on `Node`s:

To add a class to an element: [`elm.classList.add("animation")`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

To add an element as a child of another: [`parent.appendChild(elm)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) (for you, `parent` would probably be [`document.querySelector(".main")`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector))

To remove an element's child: [`parent.removeChild(elm)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild) (equivalently, `elm.parentNode.removeChild(elm)`)

Comment: Yes, it's how to do it pretty easy, but **I can't use JQuery to manipulate the DOM when I'm using React**. No?

Comment: I mean JQuery or vanilla JS

Comment: This _is_ vanilla JS, no jQuery... Read the links, they point to MDN.

Comment: Wait, you can't use vanilla JS? Why not? That doesn't make sense

Comment: It was my question. I thought ReactJS doesn't allow you to add/remove DOM elements inside its DOM. If I was mistaken, that's awesome :)

Comment: I used JQuery in my question, because it was faster.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it does. I haven't used it, but I believe the special "inline-HTML" syntax it just sugar for creating elements with normal JS methods... Why not try it out?

Comment: It works, no errors, no warnings, but I want to know how to do it right

Comment: Define "right." This is how I would normally do what you want... ReactJS isn't _that_ special. (If you really want to, you can search their documentation to see if they have any functions for this... I doubt you'll find anything, because it would just be duplicating these built-in APIs)

Comment: @qxz You are correct in thinking you shouldn't be manually manipulating the DOM unless absolutely needed.

Comment: @Chris ? Are you saying that there's a better solution in this situation?

Comment: I am, I am writing you an answer now

Comment: No, you shouldn't be manipulating the DOM directly if you're using react. I would do something like this.state = { coordinates: [ ] } in the constructor and on click add the x/y coordinates to that array. Then in the render ,map over the array and return a div for each item at that location. As for removing them, in the click function you can also include a setTimeout that does something like this.setState({ coordinates: this.state.coordinates.slice(1)})

Comment: Ah, thanks. As you can tell, I've never used React :D

Comment: You're way is valid too qxz but if you're using react, theres a "react way" to doing everything lol

Comment: @MattAft, thank you! It's what I wanted to know, double checked.